# How to create client proxy if I know service type in wcf?

Tags: wcf

How can I create client proxy if I know only the type of service ?
Is there any way , please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know the service contract. The type of the service doesn't really help.

In fact, I'm not sure why the client should know the type of the service...